# At last lines why he is using typecasting in double?

Tags: java, casting, int, double, typecast-operator

I'm new learner in java
This is just a part of the code just i need to know why he is using typecasting here and why int specially?

**double** anynumber =(int) 32/8.5;

Comment: Post the code **in the question**, as properly formatted text. Don't post a link to an image containing code. That makes the question unreadable, especially for people with vision problems.

Comment: If you cant even put some efforts to paste the code here, instead of linking a picture, why should the SO community put the efforts to help you?

Comment: Okay sorry i'm new here thanks i will put the code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:.

```
(int) 32/8.5;
```

casts `32` to an integer and not the result of the division to integer, 
because casting has higher precedence than division. 
But it is totally unnecessary since 32 is already an integer. 
So this:

```
double anynumber =(int) 32/8.5;
System.out.println(anynumber);
```

will print:

```
3.764705882352941
```

just like if the casting was not there. 
But this:

```
double anynumber =(int) (32/8.5);
System.out.println(anynumber);
```

will print:

```
3.0
```

because it applies the casting to the result of the division by truncating the decimal digits to create an integer.
So to answer your question, if you found this line of code in a book or online, 
it does not do anything different than a simple:

```
double anynumber = 32/8.5;
```